# Symfony2 Get Username in Navigation

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, bundles

I've started using Symfony2 Framework which looks very great for me.
After creating the first bundles to rebuild an existing project with Symfony2 I came to this problem:

I've created a `{% block navigation %}` in *base.html.twig*, where my navigation is placed.
Then, in my bundle, i'm extending the base.html.twig and the navigation is visible. 
Everything's fine.

My problem is that I want to show a greeting to logged in users, but the *base.html.twig* has no Logic or Container, and I'm wondering how I can "push" the user information so that I don't need to define the user information in the controller of every bundle.

At the moment, my controller action looks like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $sUser = $this->getUser();
    return $this->render('@WhatEver/index.html.twig', array(
        'sUser'  => $sUser
    ));
}
```

So my question is: **How can I manage my project so that the user information in the navigation exists from every bundle?**

**Is a Twig Extension the right way to go?
Or do I need to change the way i'm including templates?**

Thanks to everyone who can help me out with this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Symfony user can be accessed directly in Twig by using;

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me how to avoid the "Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable" error if the user is logged out?

Comment: You can also use the default filter `{{ app.user|default('Not logged in') }}`

Comment: I'll try that, too! Thank you, maybe i'll need that later :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the UserName in the Session

Then you could call it with `{{ session.username }}`

Another possibility would be the `FOS:UserBundle`. If the User is logged in you could show it with `{{ app.user.name }}`.

A third option would be a Twig Extension

Comment: Thanks mate! I'm going to use FOS:UserBundle, that seems to be the best way!

Comment: @MathisSchülingkamp You're welcome! If this answer helped you please don't forget to possible upvote and accept the answer